# Trouble Setting Up Rig for Mech Character

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

[image: Rig not attached to mesh] [image: Rig not attached to mesh#2]
First time poster and as the title says, I'm trying to rig this mech character(which was made up of different meshes then combined into one mesh)for a client who want to use it for pose reference rig. Nothing high end. Now watching a few tutorials, I have set up a rigify human meta-rig(did the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> with the scaling) and got the generated rig with the controls. The problem is no matter what, I can't get this character to rig right.
I have tried the following:

- Turned on the Auto Run Python Scripts
- Applied all of my modifiers, Recalculate Normals and deleted doubles
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to unparent the mesh in object mode before adding it to the rig
- Tried parenting with first Automatic Weights which gave me the "bone heat weighting failed" error and then tried With Empty Groups which some reason, makes my mech mesh disappears in the menu when I parent it to rig and can't click on the mech and make vertex groups to connect to the bones. I even tried parenting the mech and rig with Bone and Bone Relative and still nothing.

I'm at the point that I'm getting really frustrated with this as I tried a few troubleshoots on here and nothing worked. I use Blender 2.79b as my laptop can not support Blender 2.8+